# Como vincular uma tecla á execução de um script em Python?

Tags: python

Eu ainda não sei praticamente nada de programação, então estou com dificuldade em vincular uma tecla a execução do script. Por exeplo: eu quero fazer o ecript iniciar ao apertar a tecla Enter.

Este é o script que criei:

```python
    import pyautogui as gui
    
    import time
    
    import pyperclip as py
    
    import mouse as m
    
    Dado = 32
    
    
    gui.PAUSE = 0.5
    time.sleep(5)
    for dados in range(1,Dado):
        
        #Copie o n° do processo
        gui.hotkey('ctrl','c')
        gui.press('down')
        
        #Va para o SPG 
        gui.moveTo(277,2)
        gui.click(277,2)
        
        #Escreva o N° do Processo  
        m.click('right')
        gui.press('enter')
        gui.press('enter')
        
        #Altera a Temporalidade
        time.sleep(2)
        gui.press('5')
        gui.press('enter')
        gui.press('S')
        gui.press('enter')
        gui.press('enter')
        
    
        #Volta para a Planilha
        gui.moveTo(-500,20)
        gui.click(-500,20)
```

Comment: Quando diz *"vincular uma tecla a execução do script"* o que exatamente quer dizer. A partir do OS chamar o interpretador Python e rodar um script? Ou ao iniciar um script esse fique em estado de espera até uma determinada tecla seja pressionada e o fluxo de processamento se inicie?

Comment: Chamar o interpretador e rodar o script

Comment: Muito ampla e não parece ser um problema de linguagens de programação, está mais para uma questão sobre sistemas operacionais. Não existe uma maneira padrão, cada OS terá sua maneira individual de realizar esse vínculo entre teclas e ações.

Comment: Entendi, muito obg.

Comment: No Windows você pode criar um atalho na pasta de programas, e no próprio atalho vincular uma tecla (não precisa criar scripts adicionais), ou então fazer com que seu script registre um atalho global de tecla para a ação desejada, e executar ele na inicialização, para que aguarde a tecla.

Answer (score -3):

A maneira mais fácil de fazer esta vinculação seria pelo seu sistema operacional, criando um script que executa o seu código com o interpretador.

Em Windows seria algo como

```
@echo off
python script.py
```

salve isso como .bat no windows e coloque ele no mesmo diretório do seu script. E aí clique com botão direito, propriedades, e veincule uma tecla de atalho a ele. Não dá para ser a tecla enter, tem que ser algo como "shift + ctrl + k", algo que não esteja reservado, será problemático usar o enter.

Há opções parecidas no Linux para criar atalho, de acordo com suas distro.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).